# Control Channel Trigger on Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, triggers, stream-socket-client

I've come to a point on a Windows 8 App that (according to my research) needs a Control Channel Trigger to establish a StreamSocket connection and get the response when the app is not active.

I've been reading [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701032) and [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710181) to try to understand where should I declare a new ControlChannelTrigger, is it on my background task? Or is it where I declare a new BackGround Task? I'm getting a little confused about it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any application which will be running at background and  All the logic will be in Application. Then Add this application to windows task scheduler.

Comment: Suitable to be a comment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understood what you meant.